# Is there a git config options equivalent to the git diff -M and git merge -X rename-threshold options?

Tags: git

The `git diff` option `-M` and the `git merge` strategy option `-X rename-threshold` allow one to specify the similarity index for finding renames for that specific invocation.

Are there `git config` options that can be used to set the *default* similarity index for diff and/or merge, so that it is not necessary to specify a value each time if one wants something other than the default 50%?

Comment: [`diff.renames*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-diffrenames) seems to be the closest thing. Alternatively, you could try using an alias.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, but unfortunately there's a simple answer: "No." There's no way to set a default similarity value.